# Awk script to append suffix to column when column has duplicated values

Tags: linux, awk

**Scenario 1**

I need to do below changes only when column 1 is `CR` and column 3 has duplicates rows/values. This input-file can contain 100 of this duplicated rows of column 3

Value in column 3 to be suffix with sequence starting from `a` followed by `CR`.
if we have appended suffix till a to `z` with CR like(`aCR, bCR, cCR` till `zCR`), then next suffix will be `aaCR, abCR, acCR` and so on for column 3

Input File

```
a||c
CR||2157237496
CR||2157237496
CR||2157237496
INV||2157237496
RNV||3457634589
```

Output File

```
a||c
CR||2157237496aCR
CR||2157237496bCR
CR||2157237496cCR
INV||2157237496
RNV||3457634589
```

**Scenario 2**

Need to do this in a separate code. Below is for different file. I need to do below changes only when column 1 is DR and column 3 has duplicates rows/values. Value in column 3 to be suffix with sequence starting from `a` except for first document followed by `DR`.

If we have appended suffix till a to `z` with DR like(`aDR, bDR, cDR` till `zDR`), then next suffix will be `aaDR, abDR, acDR` ans so on for column 3

Input File

```
a||c
DR||3770022521
DR||3770022521
DR||3770022521
INV||9876543738
```

Output File

```
a||c
DR||3770022521
DR||3770022521aDR
DR||3770022521bDR
INV||9876543738
```

I tried below code, it is giving me output for scenario 2  but not able to append sequence number to column3. I am able to suffix only `a` which is static.
Here need to consider column 1 equal to `CR` for scenario 1 and `DR` for scenario 2 as well(that I'm unable to do)

```
awk -F"|" -v OFS="|" '{if(++a[$3]>1)$3=$3"a"}1' d1.txt
```

Code output :

```
a||c
CR||2157237496
CR||2157237496a
CR||2157237496a
INV||2157237496a
RNV||3457634589
```

I need to implement the scenarios 1 and 2 separately

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: hi @Kent...i need to do below changes only when column1 is CR and column3 has duplicates rows/values. This inputfile can contain 100 of this duplicated rows of column3 Value in column 3 to be suffixe with sequence starting from "a" followed by CR.
if we have appended suffix till a to z with CR like(aCR, bCR, cCR till zCR), then next suffix will be aaCR, abCR, acCR ans so on for column3

Comment: Is it ok to suffix the duplicates with index (i.e) DR1, DR2, ? Does the file contains only duplications of one value (or) there may be possibility of multiple duplications ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: As @Inian held my hand and re-read the OP to me, I edited the script to actually support duplicates. First, a bit better test data:

```
a||c
CR||2157237496
CR||2157237497
CR||2157237496
CR||2157237497
INV||2157237496
RNV||3457634589
```

An awk for scenario 1:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="|"                       # field delimiters
    ab="zabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy"  # mod safe alphabet
    d=26                             # size of alphabet
}
function i2ab(n,    b) {             # b is local var
    while(n>=1) {
        p=n%d                        # this is the letter position
        n=n/d                        # n for the next round
        n-=(n==int(n))               # fix for n%d==0 else 26 -> az, not z
        b=substr(ab,p+1,1) b         # prepend the next letter to buffer
    }
    return b                         # return buffer
} 
$1=="CR" {                           # for DR change CR to DR and ++a[$3] to a[$3]++ below
    $3=$3 i2ab(++a[$3]) $1           # increment c and map it to a string
}1' file                             # output
a||c
CR||2157237496aCR
CR||2157237497aCR
CR||2157237496bCR
CR||2157237497bCR
INV||2157237496
RNV||3457634589
```

See comments for changing it to work with scenario 2.

The function `i2ab` provides letter combinations after 26 also:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    ab="zabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy"
    d=26
    print i2ab(27)                   # I AM HERE 26 -> z, 27 ->aa
}                                           
function i2ab(n,    b) {                    #
    while(n>=1) {                           #
        p=n%d                               #
        n=n/d                               #
        n-=(n==int(n))                      #
        b=substr(ab,p+1,1) b              #####
    }                                      ###
    return b                                #
}'
aa                                    # I DID THIS
```

Comment: @Inian You're right, I guess I'll need to add an array. Thanks for reading it out loud for me. :D

Comment: Hi..@James Brown..Thank you sir..for quick response..will check and let you know for any issues

Comment: Hi @Inian..Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I can provide a way to solve the first scenario, with which you can extend to make the second one work too. It involves a two time parsing of the file but only on the selected columns on the second pass. I shall gleefully delete the answer if its able to be done in a single pass.

#### Steps

- Create the function to generate the alphabetic characters from `a-z` as needed using the `sprintf()` with the ASCII codes
- On the first pass, create a hash-map for values containing in third column for values in first column as `CR`
- On the second pass for those column again, modify the `$3` to generate the pattern you need.

The script should be something as below. Name it as `script.awk`

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk


function generateAlphabets() {
    idx = 0
    for(i=97;i<123;i++ ) {
        letters[idx++]=sprintf("%c",i)
    }
}

BEGIN {
    generateAlphabets()
    FS=OFS="|"
    counter=0
}

$1 == "CR" {
    map[$1""$3]
}

FNR == NR { next }

($1""$3 in map) {
    $3 = $3""letters[counter++]"CR"
}1
```

Run the script below as

```
awk -f script.awk file file
```

You can extend this for second scenario by putting an `awk` variable to pass `CR` or `DR` and replace the string with the variable in the code wherever applicable